# Operator precedence of PHP object indirection operator (->)

Tags: php, operators, operator-precedence

The object indirection operator (`->`) is missing from the [PHP Operator Precedence table](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) on the official documentation page. A comment on the bottom of the page says the precedence of such operator must be the highest. However, the following code shows that this is not true, and the comment is wrong:

```
class Foo {
  public $i;
  function __construct() { $this->i = 0; }
}

$foo = new Foo();
++$foo->i;
echo $foo->i;
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
```

So, what is the exact position of the object indirection operator (`->`) in the aforementioned PHP operator precedence table?

Comment: Well `->` must have a higher precedence than a pre-increment `++`, else you'd be trying to increment the `$foo` object, not the `$i` property of that object.... so the comment is correct

Comment: True, but why doesn't the PHP documentation say that -> is of higher precedence than the other operators? Why is this detail left out from the table?

Comment: In C++, the only operator of higher precedence is the [scope resolution operaotor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) which is also present in PHP. So perhaps the comment is still wrong.

Comment: Perhaps because the PHP documentors are fallible, or perhaps that they consider it so obvious that it doesn't need documenting to such a level of detail

Comment: OK, perhaps that is the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`->`operator precedence is higher than `++`, but lower than `new/clone` .Through my test it's higher than `[(array operator)` in cli and lower than `[` in Apatch httpd server, So I think this is a bug.

Comment: My php version is 5.6 and used windows